# Confused about string to var (using curly brackets) in a function

Tags: php

Can anyone tell me why this works (it echos out "poo"):

```
$input = "wee";
$val = "poo";
${$input} = $val;
echo $wee;
```

But this doesn't:

```
function bodily($input) {
    $val = "poo";
    ${$input} = $val;
}
bodily("wee");
echo $wee;
```

I want to use this sort of method to play with some $_POST vars. Please tell me if I can explain more... Cheers!

Comment: there is no point in using this sort of method to play with $_POST vars. $_POST is an array and you need square, not curly braces to access it's members.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your variable `$wee` gets only defined inside the scope of your function `bodily()`. It is not defined outside this function.

You **could** make it `global`, anyway this is not a useful pattern for a real life application:

```
function bodily($input) {
    $val = "poo";
    global ${$input}; // make your $wee defined in the global scope
    ${$input} = $val;
}
bodily("wee");
echo $wee;
```

outputs

```
poo
```

Comment: Ok thanks. Incase anyone wants to know why I wanted to do this, I'm fed up with always having to check that $_POST or $_GET vars are not empty, then whether they are set when using them. I wanted to be able to say `bodily('wee')` and that that function check for a $_POST['wee'] or $_GET['wee'] for a value, and if a value exists, stick it in a variable called $wee.

Answer (score 3):

Because the variable is defined locally inside of the function. Let the function return the value and assign it to a variable outside of the function.

Comment: Another (possible) way is to declare `$wee` as global in `bodily`.

Comment: Yes, but global variables are strongly not recommended to use! it makes the code worse to read/understand.

Answer (score 1):

Because the variables inside a function are not accessible from outside unless inside the function you use "global $var" or pass it by reference like function (&$var) ...
in order for your code to work you need

```
<?php
function bodily($input) {
    $val = "poo";
    ${$input} = $val;
    echo $wee;
}
bodily("wee");
```

Comment: Thanks Marian! I think I'll forget this altogether as comments above suggest it'll be a bad idea.